# iOS 12 Safari iframe + position: fixed + translate3d bug

Tags: html, css, iframe, mobile-safari, ios12

Any ideas how to fix this? I cannot remove any of the css properties nor the iframe as a more complex application requires those, but I am interested in some sort of workaround.

**Expected behavior:** Lime colored element is fully visible when scrolling.

**Observed behavior:** Lime colored element partially disappears when scrolled beyond a certain point.

Besides the `iframe`, `position: fixed` and `translate3d`, the bug seems to require that the `.item` is of a  certain width (>1024px on iPhone X).

[image: Screencapture of bug on iPhone X running iOS 12.1]

[Example of Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/zuoFyz/)

**index.html style**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    height: 1500px;
}

iframe {
    width: 100%;
}
```

**iframe.html markup**:
`#app > #gallery > .item`

**iframe style**

```
#app {
    height: 800px;
    font-size: 1rem;
}

#gallery {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.item {
    width: 1025px; 
    height: 800px;
    background: lime
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been having this issue for some time now and finally found a fix that works for me. Reduce the width of div disappearing (in the iframe) to make sure it's smaller than the size of the phone screen width. I tried all the css tricks (translate, touch scroll etc) and everything else all over the web. This is the only thing that has worked.